# Hive queries executing as Map only jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I recently came across a question

> **Will all Hive queries be converted into map and reduce jobs?**

I know Hive queries are converted into a series of Map Reduce jobs.I am not talking about invoking external scripts in Hive.
Is there any case where a reduce job is not required and Hive can achive the result by Map job itself.

What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. It just depends on what type of job you are running.

For example if you have a employee table with schema (Name, id , department).

The following query runs a Map only job. The Mapper recieves (Name, id , department) from hive table as the value and it emits the Name , Nullwritable .
Hence we dont need reducer for this scenario.

```
select Name from employee;
```